# Internal Server Error: TypeError in Django Rest Framework viewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am building an API using Django Rest Framework for managing assignments. I have a viewset for `Assignment` model that allows to create new assignments via a POST request to `/api/assignment/Assignment/`. However, when I make the request, I get an "Internal Server Error" with the following traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/assignment/Assignment/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\project\Assignments-Api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\project\Assignments-Api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\project\Assignments-Api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\project\Assignments-Api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\project\Assignments-Api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\project\Assignments-Api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\project\Assignments-Api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'DeferredAttribute'
```

It seems that the error occurs in the `views.py` file of Django Rest Framework, but I cannot figure out the root cause of the issue. What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it? But Data saved in the model as expected.

***update***

`views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import (
    viewsets,
    mixins,
)

from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

from rest_framework import (
    viewsets,
    mixins,
)
from assignment.models import (
    Assignment,
    Tag,
)
from assignment import serializers
from .pagination import CustomPagination


class AssignmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """View for manage assignment APIs."""

    serializer_class = serializers.AssignmentSerializer
    queryset = Assignment.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ["name", "last_updated_by"]
    pagination_class = CustomPagination


class TagViewSet(
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
):

    """Manage tags in the database."""

    serializer_class = serializers.TagSerializer
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
```

Comment: Sharing 'views.py' will be very useful. Especially when you think this is a part of the problem. To help, update your post with 'view.py' and 'urls.py' while we are at it.

Comment: @Blind2k added views.py